# ON DUPLICATE KEY still duplicating inserts

Tags: mysql

I have an issue where instead of checking to see if there's a duplicate, the script below just inserts the row into mysql, no updating at all. I've tried again and again yet there's always duplication going on.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
if ($completeStatus == "0") {

// Get the default questions responses and insert into database
$questionsAnswered = $_GET['questions'];
foreach( $questionsAnswered as $key => $answers){
    $query = "INSERT INTO survey_ResponseDetail (responseHeader,
                        questionID,
                        questionText,
                        ansLikelihood,
                        ansExpConsq,
                        ansRepRisk,
                        currWayMitigate
                    )
VALUES ('$ResponseHeader',
        '$key',
        'test1',
        '$answers[1]',
        '$answers[2]',
        '$answers[3]',
        '$answers[4]'
        )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ansLikelihood = '$answers[1]',
                        ansExpConsq = '$answers[2]',
                        ansRepRisk = '$answers[3]',
                        currWayMitigate = '$answers[4]',
                        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)";
    $dbresult = mysql_query($query) or die ('Database Error (' . mysql_errno() . ') ' . mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: Have to ask. You do have a PK or other unique constraint on the survey_ResponseDetail table. Right?

Comment: My knowledge of mySQL is horribly weak right now, so I have no idea. If I had to set it when creating the table then, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your assertion in the comments is correct, the problem is that you haven't defined a unique constraint or primary key on any fields in `survey_ResponseDetail`.

Per the MySQL Documentaiton on the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

If you don't designate a field as unique (or indirectly doing so by marking it as a PK) then MySQL has no way of knowing what a duplicate key is. Thus the command isn't doing what you expect.

If you tell me which field (or combination of fields) must be unique for each row in `survey_ResponseDetail` I will edit my answer with the code to apply the constraint you need to make this work.

Comment: Here's a screencap of my fields http://cl.ly/HTYe

Could you elaborate onto what exact uses unique rows do?

Comment: In a well designed database you need to have either a column or a combination of columns that uniquely identifies a row. In non-technical terms. If you wanted to tell someone how to find a particular row in the database, what information would you have to tell them so there was no possibility of confusion with another row. Another way to state this is: What does one row in this table represent?

Comment: Let's focus on one thing at a time. What does a single row in this table represent?

Comment: BTW: The fields in your screenshot don't match up to the fields in your query. Did you take a shot of the wrong table?

Comment: Yep, wrong screenshot - http://cl.ly/HSsc (my bad there). What I am creating is a survey, so each row would represent a response to the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12721/discussion-between-johnfx-and-keiran-lovett)

Answer (score 0):

For `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work, one of the updated / newly inserted fields must be a primary key or should have a unique index on it.

It need not be a single field. Composite keys can also be defined as unique.